# "or" condition in Elixir in pattern matching

Tags: elixir

How can I do, if I can, pattern matching with "or" condition? I need this because I have some different conditions for which action is the same?

```
case something123 do
  :a -> func1()
  :b -> func1()
  :c -> func1()
  :d -> func2()
end
```

Comment: If your actual code is more complex then maybe do different function heads and handle it that way.

Answer (score 20):

You can use `in` and lists:

```
case something123 do
  x when x in [:a, :b, :c] -> func1()
  :d -> func2()
end
```

`x in [:a, :b, :c]` expands to `x == :a or x == :b or x == :c` when the `in` macro detects it's being called from a guard statement and the RHS is a literal list (because you can't call remote functions from guards).

Comment: "in" won't work for me because my real code is more complex. what's the alternative -- "or"?

Comment: What part is more complex in your real code? Without more information, I'd say you'd have to use `if` instead of `case` because `case` does not really support arbitrary `or` patterns.

Comment: the conditions all have different parts

Comment: I don't know if this answers the OP question, but it certainly nailed my own :)

Comment: It sounds like what OP needed was `cond`.

Answer (score 6):

You can also use [cond](http://elixir-lang.org/getting-started/case-cond-and-if.html#cond) to do it.

```
cond do
  something123 == :a or something123 == :b something123 == :c ->
    func1()
  something123 == :d ->
    func2()
end
```

Comment: I need to deconstruct a value first.

Comment: @Kooooro I don't get your point. Anyway I updated it to reflect your variable names.

Comment: You could do `something123 in [:a, :b, :c]`.

Answer (score 4):

You could use multiple function heads and then multiple working function. Something along the lines of

```
def foo(%{"key" => "value"}), do: do_something()
def foo(%{"other_key" => "other_value"}), do: do_something()
def foo(map), do: do_something_else(map)

defp do_something() do
  ...
end

defp do_something_else(map) do
  ...
end
```

This would allow you to match on the data that you need, and act accordingly.